# Slope map of Singapore

Tags: singapore

Do you have any idea for a repository of readily available shapefiles for Singapore, specifically slope.

Comment: Slope is usually depicted with raster, not vector format like shapefile. Do you mean countour lines (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better on the open data stackexchange site

Answer (score 2):

You can download Digital Elevation Model (DEM) From [Earth Explorer - USGS](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), using this DEM Raster (cell size usually 30m) you can extract slope as a raster and then convert it into shapefile.

Comment: Thanks dude. I guess i have no choice but to process a DEM. Just thought someone know some readily available data. nonetheless thank you

Comment: @rodel What format do you want the data in? Something like GRASS or qgis should be able to convert between formats easily.